# How to convert database result set as JSON format in java?

Tags: java, json, api, jdbc, automation

I want to convert the result set from the db into json format, the problem is when the result set returned as multiple rows for the same id with some duplicates data.

DB example:

```
===========================================================
USER_ID         NAME          PHONE_NUMBER         CITY
===========================================================
1               JACK          079999999999        New York
1               JACK          078888888888        Las Vegas
```

**I want to make my json body looks like:**

```
{ "USER_ID": 1,"NAME": JACK,"PHONE_NUMBER":[ 079999999999, 078888888888 ], "CITY": [ New York, Las Vegas ]}
```

this is my code:

```
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                // Execute the SQL Query. Store results in ResultSet
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(Query);
                System.err.println("Executing the query please wait ...");
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd=null;
                rsmd=(ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();
                int columnsCount=rsmd.getColumnCount();


                for (int j = 1; j <= columnsCount; j++) {
                    System.err.print(rsmd.getColumnName(j) + " || ");
                }


            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            while (rs.next()) {
                int total_rows = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

                for (int i = 0; i < total_rows; i++) {
                    String columnName = rs.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i + 1).toLowerCase();
                    Object columnValue = rs.getObject(i + 1);

                    // if value in DB is null, then we set it to default value
                    if (columnValue == null){
                        columnValue = "null";
                    }

                    if (obj.has(columnName)){
                        columnName += "1";
                    }
                    obj.put(columnName, columnValue);

                }
                jsonArray.put(obj);

                System.out.print("\n");
                System.out.print("\n");

                String gsonBody = gson.toJson(jsonArray);

                System.err.println(gsonBody);
            }
            return jsonArray;
```

How can i make this general for all possible scenarios with different result set.

Comment: Your best bet is to create a custom class to store that data with some collection field like cities and numbers, and then populate it with the query. Then use an existing library to just serialize it to JSON. I doubt you can do it generally without a lot of pointless effort.

Comment: If you always want it in JSON you could look at using [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/)

Answer (score 0):

which RDBMS are you using? if Postgres/db2 is your database than you could return the resultset directly as JSON.

Comment: Actually i dont care what is the RDBMS, the purpose from writing this code for testing the web-services using automation scripts. so i want to return the db result as json format. and to compare this json object with the expected json string.

Comment: I guess you should try using https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/changes-report.html

and implement own handler something like

public class JsonResultSetHandler implements ResultSetHandler<CharSequence> {
 
 private RowProcessor<CharSequence> convert = null;
 
 public JsonResultSetHandler(){
  this(JsonRowProcessor.ROW_PROCESSOR);
 }
 
 public JsonResultSetHandler(RowProcessor<CharSequence> convert){

Answer (score 0):

#### Using SQL/JSON

In many modern RDBMS, you don't have to implement any Java logic for that. [The standard SQL way to do this is by using the SQL/JSON extensions](https://blog.jooq.org/stop-mapping-stuff-in-your-middleware-use-sqls-xml-or-json-operators-instead/). In your specific case, you could write

```sql
SELECT 
  user_id, 
  name,
  JSON_ARRAYAGG(phone_number) AS phone_number,
  JSON_ARRAYAGG(city) AS city
FROM t
GROUP BY user_id, name
```

Other dialects have different syntax for the same thing

#### Doing this in Java

Since you're asking how to do this specifically in Java, you could use [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org), which has extensive SQL/JSON support and would allow you to write the above query in a type safe way:

```java
String json =
ctx.select(
        T.USER_ID,
        T.NAME,
        jsonArrayAgg(T.PHONE_NUMBER).as(T.PHONE_NUMBER),
        jsonArrayAgg(T.CITY).as(T.CITY))
   .from(T)
   .groupBy(T.USER_ID, T.NAME)
   .fetch()
   .formatJSON();
```

The benefit would be that this would take care of emulating the JSON array aggregation for your specific dialect and version, in case you have to work around some caveats.

(Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ)

#### A side note on normalisation

In the long term, you should think about [normalising your data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). You shouldn't have duplicate entries for `USER_ID` and `NAME` in this table, as it would allow for data anomalies (e.g. different `NAME` for the same `USER_ID`)